# How to change array in string into normal array

Tags: ruby

I've got objects thats stores some data in hstore (filters), and that filters also have an arrays inside.

How to transform this arrays in string class to normal arrays?

```
OpenStruct.new(@object.filters)
=> #<OpenStruct name="sth", email="sth", phone="123", subject="[\"\", \subject1\", \"subject2\", \"subject3\"]">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`JSON`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html) or [`YAML`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html) parsers.

```
require 'json'

obj = OpenStruck.new(@object.filters)
JSON.parse obj.subject
```

Or,

```
require 'yaml'

obj = OpenStruck.new(@object.filters)
YAML.load obj.subject
```